# i18next-fs-backend save missing file for all languages

Tags: internationalization, i18next

I'm using i18next-fs-backend and I would like to generate missing.json files for all languages loaded. But for now it will create missing.json files only for the selected file defined in `lng` parameter or `fallbackLng`. But for `fallbackLng` it will add the key in the missing.json only if it not available in the default `lng` translation file.

How can I generate missing.json files for all language without restart the process ?

Answer (score 0):

Set the saveMissingTo option to “all”
https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options#missing-keys